# Wrong email or password notification/alert

Tags: php

So after user successfully logs in to his/her account, s/he should be directed to index.php and Chrome has this tiny notification on top right that says 
[image]

However when user enters wrong email or password, Chrome also has that same notification in the picture but of-course, s/he is not redirected to index.php. How can I "tell" Chrome/user that that user enters the wrong email/password?

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["email"]);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST["password"]);

//select all data by using email and password entered
$customers = $mysqli->query("select * from customer where CustomerEmail='".$email."' and CustomerPassword='".$password."'");
$customer = mysqli_num_rows($customers);

$managers = $mysqli->query("select * from manager where ManagerEmail='".$email."' and ManagerPassword='".$password."'");
$manager = mysqli_num_rows($managers);

$staffs = $mysqli->query("select * from staff where StaffEmail='".$email."' and StaffPassword='".$password."'");
$staff = mysqli_num_rows($staffs);

echo $customer.'<br>';
echo $manager.'<br>';
echo $staff.'<br>';

    //if customer is true
    if($customer== 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customers);
        $id= $row['CustomerID'];
        $email = $row['CustomerEmail'];
        $name = $row['CustomerName'];

        //start session
        session_start();
        //create session
        $_SESSION['CustomerID'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['CustomerEmail'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['CustomerName'] = $name;

        //redirect page to index.php    
        header("Location: index.php");
        }

    //if manager is true
    else if($manager == 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($managers);
        $id = $row['ManagerID'];
        $email = $row['ManagerEmail'];
        $name = $row['ManagerName'];

        //start session
        session_start();
        //create session
        $_SESSION['ManagerID'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['ManagerEmail'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['ManagerName'] = $name;

        //redirect page to managerCP.php
        header("Location: managercp.php");
        }

    //if staff is true
    else if($staff == 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($staffs);
        $id = $row['StaffID'];
        $email = $row['StaffEmail'];
        $name = $row['StaffName'];

        //start session
        session_start();
        //create session
        $_SESSION['StaffID'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['StaffEmail'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['StaffName'] = $name;

        //redirect page to staffCP.php
        header("Location: staffcp.php");
        }

    //if all condition is false 
    else    {
//alert will be appeared

echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">alert("The combination of email and password do not match");document.location.href="index.php"</script>';
//header ("Location:index.php");
}
```

Okay. So the alert works but the problem isit displays white screen and I have to click "ok" before redirecting back to index.php. I want the alert to appear on index.php. Help

Comment: On what planet is `alert()` a PHP function?

Comment: try to put `autocomplete="off"` in your login form

Comment: I don't think you can tbh. I believe it has to do with your input type being a password inside your form  You can try ```autocomplete="off"``` in your password input but that will most likely disable it even if they get it right

Comment: I tried but it didn't work @Dinesh

Comment: You could just prevent form submission on wrong username or password, although that would mean using AJAX to do so.

Comment: try this `<form action="your_action.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">`

Comment: Also did not work @Dinesh